# Regex for Alternating Numbers

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a regex pattern for phone numbers consisting of 9 fixed digits.

I want to identify numbers that have two numbers alternating for four times such as `5XYXYXYXY`

I used the below sample

```
number = 561616161
```

I tried the below pattern but it is not accurate

```
^5(\d)(?=\d\1).+
```

can someone point out what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe I'm on the wrong track here, but if you want to match `5` followed by 4 same pairs of digits, I'd just use [`^5(\d\d)\1{3}$`](https://regex101.com/r/5k8FXS/1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use:

```
^(?=\d{9}$)\d*(\d)(\d)(?:\1\2){3}\d*$
```

### Demo

Here is an explanation of the pattern:

- `^` from the start of the number
- `(?=\d{9}$)` assert exactly 9 digits
- `\d*` match optional leading digits
- `(\d)` capture a digit in `\1`
- `(\d)` capture another digit in `\2`
- `(?:\1\2){3}` match the XY combination 3 more times
- `\d*` more optional digits
- `$` end of the number

Answer (score 4):

If you want to repeat 4 times 2 of the same pairs and matching 9 digits in total:

```
^(?=\d{9}$)\d*(\d\d)\1{3}\d*$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=\d{9}$)` Positive lookahead, assert 9 digits till the end of the string
- `\d*` Match optional digits
- `(\d\d)\1{3}` Capture group 1, match 2 digits and then repeat what is captured in group 1 3 times
- `\d*` Match optional digits
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uAWGC5/1)

If you want to match a pattern repeating 4 times 2 digits where the 2 digits are not the same:

```
^(?=\d{9}$)\d*((\d)(?!\2)\d)\1{3}\d*$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=\d{9}$)` Positive lookahead, assert 9 digits till the end of the string
- `\d*` Match optional digits
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `(\d)` Capture **group 2**, match a single digit
  - `(?!\2)\d` Negative lookahead, assert not the same char as captured in group 2. If that is the case, then match a single digit
- `)` Close group 1
- `\1{3}` Repeat the captured value of capture group 1 3 times
- `\d*` Match optional digits
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RTVg6Y/1)

Comment: I forgot the 9 digit requirement, your answer made me realize +1.

Comment: Was writing an answer but noticed yours. I came up with `^(?=\d{9}$)\d?((\d)(?!\2)\d)(?:\d?\1){3}\d?$` which is a small addition to allow the random digit to appear anywhere since the captured digits do not have to be in sequence (4x). Anyways, that's how I read it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Its all good, have a green one :-)

Comment: @JvdV That also clever, you can post that one so this thread has all possibilities covered :-)

Comment: @Thefourthbird Other inverted possibilities matching [the first](https://regex101.com/r/uAWGC5/2) and [second variant](https://regex101.com/r/RTVg6Y/2) for having those mentioned as well :) Have a good Sunday 4th bird!

Answer (score 2):

1. My first guess from OP's self tried regex `^5(\d)(?=\d\1).+` without any own additions was a regex is needed to verify numbers starting with `5` and followed by 4 pairs of same two digits.

   ```
   ^5(\d\d)\1{3}$
   ```

   [Demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/5k8FXS/1)
2. The same idea with the "added guess" to disallow all same digits like e.g. `511111111`

   ```
   ^5((\d)(?!\2)\d)\1{3}$
   ```

   [Demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/5k8FXS/2)
3. Guessing further that `5` is a variable value and assuming if one variable at start/end with the idea of taking out invalid values early - already having seen the other nice provided answers.

   ```
   ^(?=\d?(\d\d)\1{3})\d{9}$
   ```

   [Demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uAWGC5/2)
4. Solution 3 with solution 2's assumption of two different digits in first pairing.

   ```
   ^(?=\d?((\d)(?!\2)\d)\1{3})\d{9}$
   ```

   [Demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/RTVg6Y/2)

Solutions 3 and 4 are most obvious playings with [@4thBird's nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73844009/5527985) in changed order.